# Xcode console print weird error

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, console

It appeared after migrating project to Swift 4.1

**W0423 16:38:46.366578       1 commandlineflags.cc:1503] Ignoring RegisterValidateFunction() for flag pointer 0x10adafe00: no flag found at that address**

How do I fix it?

Comment: Seeing this with a brand new Swift4.1 project - Tab Bar template, added a few map SDKs for some testing.

Comment: I am also seeing this error, and I have a fresh new project just with 3 pods
'RealmSwift'
'SnapKit', '~> 4.0.0'
'GoogleMaps'

Comment: I can assume that the error is from Google Maps
https://github.com/googlei18n/google-input-tools/blob/master/client/base/commandlineflags.cc

Comment: Product->Clean and removing Derived data fixed the issue for me

Comment: @Kalikanth040494 I tried to do so. Doesn't help.

Comment: none of the solutions work for me So, I just ignore this warning.

Comment: facing the same issue.. driving me crazy ..i dont know yet if it affects me in some way..

Comment: For me just clean & rebuild was enough to fix this.

Comment: Did you find the answer?

Comment: (https://stackoverflow.com/a/58502622/7077168)! Hope this solve your problem

Answer (score 2):

I was helped to roll back to a later version. pod 'GoogleMaps', '~> 2.6.0' for example.

Answer (score -1):

To provide an Google Maps API key helped for me.

Comment: I did provide keys for GMSPlacesClient and GMSServices