# Ignoring RegisterValidateFunction() for flag pointer 0x10ef76ec0: no flag found at that address in Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode

How can I fix the issue?

> W0721 13:54:19.105928 1 commandlineflags.cc:1503] Ignoring RegisterValidateFunction() for flag pointer 0x10ef76ec0: no flag found at that address

Comment: Seems to be duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49982778/xcode-console-print-weird-error

Comment: any one got solution yet ?

Answer (score 2):

This problem occurs because your code try to using non-existing pointer in cocoa pods. You may using framework that using cocoa pods and install needed pods on the main project.

The solution is to make cocoa pods version similar in both framework and project , run `pod update` from the terminal in both  framework and project **or** specify every pod version to be same in both

**Example**

framework pod file :

```
pod 'GooglePlaces' '~> 3.1.0'
```

project pod file :

```
pod 'GooglePlaces' '~> 3.1.0'
```

I hope this solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this error when I had a `UITableView` in a view controller and:

1. I connected the `DataSource` and `Delegate` for table view in the Storyboard.
2. I did NOT declare the `UIViewController` as `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource`.

I usually assign delegate/datasource in code (which would have given me a warning).